# Is there a place I can place this code to not have to repeat it for every page (ASP.NET CORE Razor pages)

Tags: asp.net, session, .net-core, layout

I have this code at the top of every razor page:

```
public override void OnPageHandlerExecuting(PageHandlerExecutingContext context)
{
    base.OnPageHandlerExecuting(context);

    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("first_name") == null)
    {
        context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Authentication/Login");
    }
}
```

I wanted to stick this in the _layout page but it doesn't come with a cs file.

I just want to check if they are logged in. I would rather do this in the _layout file (makes sense), but I guess Microsoft had a better idea.

Comment: `HttpContext.Session.GetString("first_name")` - interesting way to check if user is logged in. Any particular reason to use it instead of framework provided support for auth?

Comment: What framework are you referring to? This was just the way I did it in Codeigniter and it was very easy. ASP.NET is proving to be far more complex and difficult. Not as advertised.

Comment: I'm referring  to ASP.NET Core framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create something like a "Master Controller" that has your override in it and then let a normal Controller inherit from that.

So first create a Master.

```
namespace YourNameSpace.Controllers
{
    public class MasterController : Controller
    {
        //your code for every page
    }
}
```

And then use this in every Controller

```
namespace YourNameSpace.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class HomeController : MasterController
    {

    }
}
```